# C# with plsql in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plsql-package

How to write the crud application with plsql package?

Logic should be implemented using plsql function and procedures and bundled as Oracle package.

Comment: Why are you using VS 2010?

Comment: This is the requirement to use in our university

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace package body details_pkg is


     PROCEDURE details(
                 emp_details OUT T_CURSOR_SELECT
     )

     IS CURSORREF T_CURSOR_SELECT;
     BEGIN

        OPEN CURSORREF FOR SELECT * FROM Employees;
        emp_details:= CURSORREF;

     END details;
end details_pkg;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to design a CRUD operation using c#. I also dont understand why specifically restricing to VS 2010, when VS 2017/19 are available. You can use various libraries such as Entity Framework, Dapper etc. To connect with Oracle, i am sure they do have the nuget pkgs that you can refer to and make use of the PL/SQL functions/Stored Procs.

I see this is an university sub, so it expects and involves learning. I would recommend to explore these, and learn. To begin with, you can use the standard Oracle libraries (as nugets) and write your own implementation. Entity Framework (EF), Dappers are great wrappers and segregate the code from backend dependencies. I am not sure if this question is complete, but with what i could get from, these are some suggestions.